# Modify bootstrap modal to have some sort of pointer come out of the border?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good afternoon everyone!

I've been looking around, but this is a tough question to word, and have had no luck finding people with similar questions/solutions.

Anyway, I'm using bootstrap modals to try and help a new user navigate through menus for the first time.  Basically, I'm trying to use a modal to "point" them in the right direction.

I'm not having problems changing the position of the modal, but I think it would be nice to not have the modal in the general area they need to click, but maybe to point to the menu item we are instructing them to push.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this using bootstrap modals?

So here is an example where I moved the modal to under the "Home banner" on the left.  It would be cool to somehow in the top left of the modal point to the banner, if it makes sense.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ModalPractice2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ModalPractice.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-static">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b>Modal Practice</b></a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <input type="button" id="btnOpenModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gettingStartedTwo" class="btn btn-info btn-lg newLocation" style="display: none;" />
        <div id="gettingStartedTwo" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button id="btnCloseModalTwo" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title">Your Next Steps</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Click on the Modal Practice banner to go to the homepage.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnModalTwo">OK</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnOpenModal").click();

    $("#btnModalTwo").click(function() {
         $("#btnCloseModalTwo").click();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#gettingStartedTwo {
    top: 5%;
    right: 30%;
    outline: none;
}

.navbar {
  background-color:#669933;
    color:#88c53f;
    border-radius:0;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#88c53f;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    border-left:1px solid #085C33;
}
.navbar-nav > li:last-child > a {
    border-right:1px solid #085C33;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#085C33;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color:#88c53f;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Try coding something, and give us your code and we'll help you with fixing it. I think this is what stackoverflow about.

Comment: you can try with this http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/

Comment: ayadi, here is an example I through together where I'm looking for some way to try and point from the modal to the "home banner" instructing the user that clicking it will bring them to the home page.

Comment: Thanks Juan, I'll take a look at that too and see if it helps